# Swift 4 Switch relate to label on tableView

Tags: swift, switch-statement, tableview

I have problem to get label from cell when i turn my switch **ON**. I do fetch all labels from Firebase Database.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tagCell", for: indexPath) as! TagsTableViewCell
    print(myCallList[indexPath.row])
    let _tag = myCallList[indexPath.row]
    cell.tagLabel?.text = _tag.type

    return cell
}
```

[image]

**UPDATED:**
UITableViewCell contain nothing special

```
import UIKit

class TagsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tagLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tagSwitch: UISwitch!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

My model:

```
class Calls: NSObject {
    var type: String?

    init(type: String?) {
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

LoadCalls contain Firebase data fetch:

```
func LoadCalls() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        self.myCallList.removeAll()
        ref.child("tags").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot != nil{
                var tagType = snapshot.key as? String
                let myCalls = Calls(type: tagType)
                self.myCallList.append(myCalls)
                print(self.myCallList.count)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tagsTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: You want the table view controller to get a call with cell label value when switch changes?

Comment: What is the type of `myCallList`? And could you add the code for the `TagsTableViewCell` class

Comment: @Carpsen90 i update the code.. myCallList is NSObject.

Comment: @Augie correct... i want to get label.text when switch is ON. For example if switch_2 is ON i want to get label_2.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it something like this - add tag to switcher and create action for it

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tagCell", for: indexPath) as! TagsTableViewCell
    print(myCallList[indexPath.row])
    let _tag = myCallList[indexPath.row]
    cell.tagLabel?.text = _tag.type
    cell.switcher.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

And after this

```
@IBAction func switcherChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
   var getLabel = myCallList[(sender as AnyObject).tag]
   print(getLabel.type)
}
```

Comment: Perfect! It works... just little fix
var getLabel = myCallList[(sender as AnyObject).tag]
print(getLabel.type)

Comment: This is quick answer and variant, really better way is to do it as Augie told via delegate

Comment: Sad that i can't mark both answers as correct... but it really helpful your both answers

Answer (score 1):

A delegate / protocol for communication between cell and table controller can work well here.

```
protocol switchCellDelegate : Class {
     func cellSwitchChanged( value: String, sender: Any)
}
```

update table view cell with property and IBAction for switch change

```
class TagsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

     weak var delegate : switchCellDelegate?

     @IBAction func switchChanged(sender: UISwitch){
         guard let delegate = delegate else { return }
         if sender.isOn {
              delegate.cellSwitchChanged( value: tagLabel.text, sender: self)
          }
     }
```

and then in cellForRowAtIndex, add this

```
cell.delegate = self
```

and controller

```
extension myController : switchCellDelegate {
     func cellSwitchChanged( value: String, sender: Any){
         //do what you want here
     }
}
```